# PHP iconv() translates "ä" to "ae" but it should be "a"

Tags: php, linux, locale, translation, iconv

So, i've used iconv() to produce URL-safe (and in other contexts as well) versions of swedish words for a long time, so the word `Stadsnät` becomes `Stadsnat` but I've just moved to a new server and noticed that it gets translated to `Stadsnaet` instead, breaking a lot of the links, how do I get iconv() to go back to the "dumber" `ä -> a` instead of the probably more correct `ä -> ae`?

It doesn't seem to be a function of PHP, on my develop server it's converted correctly, but not on my production server, and both use the same setlocale() but I guess the locale files in the system may differ.

Any ideas?

Comment: are both systems the linux / windows?

Comment: @Isitar Yes, both are Linux, so I'm guessing it's something about the locale information in the system

Comment: Related: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php#105507

Comment: @k0pernikus Yes, I've seen that, but that didn't help me, for unknown reasons

Comment: Do you see a difference on your development and production server if you run `locale` in a terminal? Do you have the same version of php running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have not specified setLocale correctly.

with this small example you can see the difference:

```
<?php
$str = 'Stadsnät';

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');
$translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
echo $translit . PHP_EOL;
// echos Stadsnat


setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_CH');
$translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);

echo $translit . PHP_EOL;
// echos Stadsnaet
```

try this small script on both servers to be sure.

**EDIT:**

Based on the conversation in the comment:
`setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')` solved the problem.

As an alternative the following Code should do the same:

```
transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\uffff] remove', 'Stadsnät')
```

Comment: have you executed exactly this script on both servers? no other framework bootstrapping stuff, just this simple script?

Comment: Yes, I get "Stadsnaet Stadsnaet"

Comment: can you try with setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.utf8');

Comment: Yes, I've tried several different versions, none do anything... Damn...

Comment: have you tried using the transliterator? `echo transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\uffff] remove', 'Stadsnät') . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Solved it! I needed to use the en_US.UTF8 locale, that one I hadn't tried. Phew, thanks! I'll set this as the correct answer